# Python dictionary having tuple keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

What I like to have is a dictionary in the format of `{(x1,y1):(a1,b1,c1),(x2,y2):(a2,b2,c2),(x3,y3):(a3,b3,c3),...}`

All the data is in a text file in a format like this:

```
x1 y1 a1
...
x1 y1 b1
...
x1 y1 c1
...
x2 y2 a2
...
x2 y2 b2
...
x2 y2 c2 
...
```

I read the text file but I don't know how to associate the a, b, c values with the corresponding key.

The script I have right now gives me `{(x1,y1):c1,(x2,y2):c2,(x3,y3):c3,...}` which is not correct

Since I read the lines one by one, I am not sure how I can save the a , b values.

Comment: 1) Tuples are immutable - you want a different data structure to update new values. 2) Post your code to get some feedback!

Comment: Would a dictionary in the form `{(x1,y1):[a1,b1,c1],...}` be acceptable? That is a dictionary that maps tuples to lists?

Comment: What do the `...` mean in your file format?  Are they literals?  Are they there to show that the rows that go together might not be grouped together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    answer = {}
    for line in infile:
        x,y,v = line.split()
        k = (x,y)
        if k not in answer:
            answer[k] = []
        answer[k].append(v)
answer = {k:tuple(v) for k,v in answer.items()}
```

Of course, you could use `collections.defaultdict` to ease your burden just a little:

```
import collections
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in infile:
        x,y,v = line.split()
        answer[(x,y)].append(v)
answer = {k:tuple(v) for k,v in answer.items()}
```

Comment: Try `collections.defaultdict`, it will eliminate the `if k not in answer` clause.

Comment: @Robᵩ: very true. But since OP is a beginner, I didn't want to add a dependency. Updating answer

Comment: I understand your pedagogy and defer to your judgement. +1

Comment: @Robᵩ: Just added the `collections.defaultdict`. Thanks for mentioning it

Comment: May as well combine `k = (x,y)` `answer[k].append(v)` into `answer[x, y].append(v)`

Comment: Adding the collection and answer = collections.defaultdict(list) line and defining the Value as list solved the problem. I appreciate this